# Passing PHP variable outside PHP OOP class (from separate PHP file) onto node value of a HTML <span> tag in a JQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, reference, scope

It is possible to pass a reference in a PHP variable that is taken from inside scope of an instantiated object class (PHP) into the JQuery function, in order for it render to a number or string to display the number of items added? I have a code here something like this:

```
<!--in cart.php-->
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#cart').replaceWith('<div id=\'cart2\'><span><?php echo ('.**$itemcount**.'); ?> </span> <a href=\'viewcart.html\' class=\'view-cart\'>View Cart</a><a class=\'checkout\' href=\'checkout.html\'>Checkout</a></div>');
});
```

where `$itemcount` is a stored variable in PHP external file called store.php

many thanks for assistance!

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question to say the least...

Lets say store.php looks like this:

```
<?php
class store {
    private $_itemcount = 0;
    public function getItemCount(){

         return $this->_itemcount;

    }
}
?>
```

From there we go like this in cart.php:

```
<?php
    $store = new store();
    $itemcount = $store->getItemCount();

    echo <<<html
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div#cart').replaceWith("<div id='cart2'><span>$itemcount</span><a href='viewcart.html' class='view-cart'>View Cart</a><a class='checkout' href='checkout.html'>Checkout</a></div>");
    });
html;
?>
```

This way, we can return the value and use it in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

store.php

```
<?php $itemcount = 10; ?>
```

in cart.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#cart').replaceWith('<div id=\'cart2\'><span><?php require 'store.php'; echo $itemcount; ?> </span> <a href=\'viewcart.html\' class=\'view-cart\'>View Cart</a><a class=\'checkout\' href=\'checkout.html\'>Checkout</a></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of answers here that will work with a string or number, but if your requirements develop any more complexity you'll run into problems.

If needed you can serialize a PHP object to JSON which will allow you to create a JavaScript object that can be used directly by JavaScript / JQuery code.

Assuming your cart.php script has access to the object from store.php represented by $phpObject:

e.g.

```
...
$(document).ready(function() {
   var jsPhpObject = <?php echo json_encode($phpObject); ?>; // doesn't need to be inside document.ready if required elsewhere
   $('div#cart').replaceWith("<div id='cart2'><span>" + jsPhpObject.property + "</span><a href='viewcart.html' class='view-cart'>View Cart</a><a class='checkout' href='checkout.html'>Checkout</a></div>");
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**store.php**

```
<?PHP
class SomeClass
{
    public $insideMemberNum;

    public function __construct()
    {
        global $outsideNum;
        $insideNum = 2;
        $this->insideMemberNum = 2;

        // 1. $outsideNum = $insideNum; (this will make $outsideNum = 2, even outside this class)
        // 2. $outsideNum = &$insideNum; (this will make $outsideNum = 2, but only wihtin this scope, after it will go back to 1)

        // so youre options are...
        //  1. pass by value
        //  2. create a public variable and store the number in there
        //  3. create a private variable and a public function to return the value of that variable like someone else suggested
    }
}
?>
```

**incart.php**

```
<?PHP


$outsideNum = 1;
echo $outsideNum . "<br />";  // prints out 1

include("store.php"); // include the external file
$obj = new SomeClass(); // instansiate the object


echo $outsideNum . "<br />"; // option 1 prints out 2, option 2 prints out 1
echo $obj->insideMemberNum . "<br />"; // prints out 2

?>
```